# Failed to create the service The submitted field 'KML_FOLDER' does not exist in the table 'db_8bog9.hsu_gk2bm.company_layers_wfl1_horizon_lines'

Tags: arcgis-pro, web-mapping, arcgis-portal

Receiving an error when trying to share a webmap to portal using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.3,

Failed to create the service 'Hosted/Company_Layers_WFL1.FeatureServer'. The submitted field 'KML_FOLDER' does not exist in the table 'db_8bog9.hsu_gk2bm.company_layers_wfl1_horizon_lines'.

The thing I cannot figure out is the specific table does not have a field named 'KML_FOLDER" and I looked through all ~80 of the layers in this webmap and none of them have a Field with that name. My Enterprise set up is 10.7.1 and SQL Server.

Below are the fields in this layer that is being referenced in the Error. I cannot simply remove this layer as it is rather important.
[image]

Comment: When you attempt to publish/share to Portal, is there anything on the config options for the feature service that references KML output?

Comment: I think I found the issue, some had Z Values and some did not, so that was causing the problems. I copied them all to a geodatabase and disabled the Z-Values and it worked. Thanks!